# Python: Replace names in a for loop from excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, for-loop, web-scraping

I have a spreadsheet with a column of CIK numbers and a column of url. I want to create a for loop for url column and get an excel output for every url which is named as the corresponding CIK number. I get stuck on this problem for a long time. Thank you for your help!

[ExcelSpreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDdXf.png)

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
import os
import time
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen


#headers={"Content-Type":"text"}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'moxiao@msu.edu'}

# open the file
data=pd.read_excel('/content/experiment.xlsx')
# get the urls
urls=data.URL
CIK=data.CIK




for CIK, url in CIK, urls:
  Cash=[]
  response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
  response.raise_for_status()
  time.sleep(0.1)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
  for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
      for row_num in range(len(tr)): 
        row = [] 
        for td in tr.find_all('td'):
          for row_item in td.get_text(strip=True):
            try:
              if row_item[0] == 'Cash and cash equivalent':
                aa = re.sub("(\xa0)|(\n)|,","",row_item.text)
                row.append(aa)
            except IndexError:
              continue
        Cash.append(row)

  df = pd.DataFrame(data=Cash)
  df.to_excel(f'/content/{CIK}.xlsx')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate bit more with your question? You want excel file with CIK and contents from the url associated with it right?

Comment: Yes. I want the file name is CIK number and file content is from URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for CIK, url in CIK, urls` is not a valid Python construction. Did you mean

```
for single_CIK, url in zip(CIK, urls)
```